# Hiding .DS_store from scandir()

Tags: php

I am having some problems with a little script that outputs file from a particular directory into a table but it output the annoying .DS_store file as I am running this app on a mac.

Here is my script to put - I have tried various methods that either stop the script working altogether or has no effect.

```
<?php

echo '<table>';

$dir = 'archive/';
$files = scandir($dir, 0);
for($i = 2; $i < count($files); $i++)
    echo '<tr>
          <td>' . $files[$i]. '</td>
          <td><a href="' . $files[$i]. '" download><button>Download</button></a>
          <a href=""></a></td>
          </tr>';

echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: `if ($files[$i] != '.DS_store')`

Comment: Check [https://github.com/xiaozhuai/odourless](https://github.com/xiaozhuai/odourless), I made a tool for preventing .DS_Store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to ignore all files that begin with a '.'

`._whatever` : These files are created on volumes that don't natively support HFS.

`.Trash` : Used to store files thrown in the Trash but haven't yet been deleted.

`.Spotlight-V100` : Stores metadata indexes and indexing rules for Spotlight.

```
<?php

echo '<table>';

$dir = 'archive/';
$files = scandir($dir, 0);
for($i = 2; $i < count($files); $i++)
  if (preg_match("/^[^\.].*$/", $files[$i])) {
    echo '<tr>
      <td>' . $files[$i]. '</td>
      <td><a href="' . $files[$i]. '" download><button>Download</button></a>
      <a href=""></a></td>
      </tr>';
  }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: That is perfect and what I was looking for! It makes sense how you come to that now, I almost had it by using the pre_match but it needed to be in an IF statement as per your answer.